# Не понимаю почему код работает именно так и как исправить это

Tags: python

Вот мой код:

```
a = input()
print(-15 > a <= 12)
```

Я хочу чтобы переменная которая больше -15
и меньше 12 при выводе выводилось True, но работает все наоборот

Comment: примите ответ, если он вам помог -- галочка слева от ответа

Comment: Почему же тогда вы пишете в условии -15 *больше* `a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-15 > a <= 12` значит, что должны быть одновременно исполнены 2 условия, именно

- `-15 > a` (т. е. `-15` более чем `а`, что то же самое как `а` **меньше** чем `-15`), и
- `a <= 12` (т.е. `а` меньше или равно `12`).

Вы вероятно хотели в первом условии (`-15 > a`) применить **обратный** знак неравенства:
`-15 < a`.

Значит, вашу вторую команду нужно исправить на

```
print(-15 < a <= 12)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a = int(input())
print(-15 < a <= 12)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = int(input())
print(a > -15 and a <= 12)
```